# Scrapy select <a> element with multiple attribute

Tags: python, xpath, attributes, scrapy

I am using Scrapy to crawl a [google results page](https://www.google.com/search?q=anaheim%20pet%20friendly%20vacation%20rentals):

Under `response.xpath('//*[@id="ires"]/ol/div/h3/a')`, I want to select `data-href` attribute.

However, it gave me an empty list when I tried `response.xpath('//*[@id="ires"]/ol/div/h3/a/@data-href')`

I wanted to ask what is the correct xpath expression to select this attribute. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't see any `data-href` in HTML.

Comment: really? I can see `href`, `onmousedown`, `data-href`. However I can not upload a picture.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The HTML that `Scrapy` receives is not the same you see in the browser, Scrapy itself is not a browser, there is no JavaScript engine built into it. Debug your site with a Scrapy Shell first.

In this case, you need to use `href` instead of `data-href`:

```
//*[@id="ires"]/ol/div/h3/a/@href
```

Demo from the shell:

```
$ scrapy shell https://www.google.com/search?q=anaheim%20pet%20friendly%20vacation%20rentals
>>> response.xpath('//*[@id="ires"]/ol/div/h3/a/@href').extract()
[u'/url?q=http://www.bringfido.com/lodging/rentals/city/anaheim_ca_us/&sa=U&ved=0ahUKEwjttJG3m9DKAhWDqh4KHeXpBvsQFggoMAA&usg=AFQjCNFFYOmY4s-kml5a23XklwzDTSGq1w', u'/url?q=https://www.flipkey.com/pet-friendly-anaheim-vacation-rentals/g29092/s/&sa=U&ved=0ahUKEwjttJG3m9DKAhWDqh4KHeXpBvsQFgguMAE&usg=AFQjCNHuXcfNgk-1JjL0xb8sl2V3AkiS8A', u'/url?q=http://www.tripadvisor.com/VacationRentals-g659482-Reviews-zfn1-Orange_County_California-Pet_Friendly_Vacation_Rentals.html&sa=U&ved=0ahUKEwjttJG3m9DKAhWDqh4KHeXpBvsQFgg0MAI&usg=AFQjCNG0n1JiCRpWthVuxL_b1ObwTW4JaA', u'/url?q=https://www.airbnb.com/explore/anaheim--ca/vacation-rentals/pet-friendly&sa=U&ved=0ahUKEwjttJG3m9DKAhWDqh4KHeXpBvsQFgg6MAM&usg=AFQjCNEDRLlfnPeWHxs5mGDzObFBZhmqBQ', u'/url?q=https://www.homeaway.com/vacation-rentals/california/anaheim/r6842&sa=U&ved=0ahUKEwjttJG3m9DKAhWDqh4KHeXpBvsQFgg_MAQ&usg=AFQjCNGcQ-Sxb3aPdoJZoxwU7vmAeYmVgA', u'/url?q=http://www.petvacationhomes.com/search/cityListing/st/California.html&sa=U&ved=0ahUKEwjttJG3m9DKAhWDqh4KHeXpBvsQFghIMAU&usg=AFQjCNG1XG-D5hyBAMfl12J-9P5VyEAOCg', u'/url?q=https://www.vacationhomerentals.com/California/Orange-County/Anaheim-vacation-rentals/g2769/&sa=U&ved=0ahUKEwjttJG3m9DKAhWDqh4KHeXpBvsQFghOMAY&usg=AFQjCNFV8DrK4dwWT0N9DiGEWZLo7n3PjA', u'/url?q=https://www.vacationhomerentals.com/California/Orange-County/Anaheim-pet-friendly-vacation-rentals/g2769/s/&sa=U&ved=0ahUKEwjttJG3m9DKAhWDqh4KHeXpBvsQFghTMAc&usg=AFQjCNEoTBZTYE7ydwWo2w3XHHUq3pcObQ', u'/url?q=https://www.vrbo.com/vacation-rentals/usa/california/orange-county/anaheim-area/anaheim&sa=U&ved=0ahUKEwjttJG3m9DKAhWDqh4KHeXpBvsQFghYMAg&usg=AFQjCNHi7YS2PmqTdMTYcv_u8NrblweE2g', u'/url?q=http://vacationrentals.travel.aol.com/listings/location-Anaheim--CA&sa=U&ved=0ahUKEwjttJG3m9DKAhWDqh4KHeXpBvsQFgheMAk&usg=AFQjCNFORzePpDlTr87Wn2gy4bjUxjf6mg']
```

Comment: From my shell `//*[@id="ires"]/ol//div/h3/a/@href` and `//*[@id="ires"]/ol/div/h3/a/@href` actually gave out the same results. Also, I was looking at the attribute `data-href` instead of `href`. @furas said s/he did not see it. I was wondering can you see it?

Comment: Would you please explain why `//div` should be used in stead of `/div`? Thanks.

Comment: @chchannn you are right, there is no need for double slash - the html got by scrapy is different from that of you see in the browser. I don't see the `data-href` for some reason too. `"data-href" in response.body` is `False`.

Comment: Would you add "the html got by scrapy is different from that of you see in the browser" to the answer? I found out this was the reason. I will mark it as a solution then.